# Can I be notified when a listener unsubscribes?

Tags: c#, events

**Summary**

1. I have a simple class that exposes a property of type `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`.
2. When this property is accessed for the first time, quite a bit of data is generated.
3. The generated data is time dependent and so will change over time - hence the need for the property to be of type `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`.
4. This is working as expected, however the generated dataset is large enough that over the lifetime of the application it is guaranteed I will run into memory issues.

**Problem**

I need to be able to delete the references to the generated data so it can be collected by the GC. The thing is though, I cannot do this unless I know that there are no listeners on the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` - or more precisely the underlying `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event.

Is there a way I can easily be notified when a listener unsubscribes from an event without implementing said event?

One way around it which would be rather simple but perhaps a bit hacky is to keep track of all Storage objects that have active data and every so often call the `CleanDataSet` method if there are no listeners to the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event.

**Sample Code**

```
public class Storage
{

    //The regular computation of the data set is not shown as it is not relevant
    //to the issue at hand.

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<String> Data
    {
        get
        {
            if (DataList == null)
            {
                DataList = new ObservableCollection<String>();
                DataReadOnly = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<String>(DataList);
                ComputeDataSet();
                //I require a way of 'listening' when the
                //DataList.CollectionChanged gains or loses a subscriber.
            }
            return DataReadOnly;
        }
    }

    private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<String> DataReadOnly;
    private ObservableCollection<String> DataList;

    private void ComputeDataSet()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (Int32 counter = 0; counter < 10000; counter++)
            DataList.Add(random.Next().ToString());
    }

    private void CleanDataSet()
    {
        DataReadOnly = null;
        DataList = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that `ReadOnlyObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` is virtual, and an event returns `null` if there are no subscribers:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var innerCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "foo", "bar" };
        var collection = (INotifyCollectionChanged)new MyReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(innerCollection);
        
        collection.CollectionChanged += Handler;
        
        innerCollection.Add("baz");
        
        collection.CollectionChanged -= Handler;
    }
    
    private static void Handler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.NewItems[0]);   
    }
}

public class MyReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> : ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T>
{
    public MyReadOnlyObservableCollection(ObservableCollection<T> list) : base(list) { }
    
    private event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler InnerEvent;
    
    protected override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (InnerEvent == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Got our first subscriber");
            }
            InnerEvent += value;
        }
        
        remove
        {
            InnerEvent -= value;
            if (InnerEvent == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There are no more subscribers");
            }
        }
    }
    
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        InnerEvent?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

We override the `CollectionChanged` event, and provide our own add and remove handlers. These handlers delegate to an inner event (we could just have used a delegate here, but an event's `+=` is thread-safe, whereas a delegate's is not). In the remove handler, we also test to see whether the inner event is `null`: if it is, there are no more subscribers.

We also need to override `OnCollectionChanged` to call our inner event.

At this point we've almost rewritten `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`, however: it's [not a big class](https://source.dot.net/#System.ObjectModel/System/Collections/ObjectModel/ReadOnlyObservableCollection.cs,0aa249269463afa5).

Comment: Oh, I rather expected the `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` to be a bit larger than that. Thank you. Also, I wasn't aware the source code for C# was publicly available, the CLI yes, but not the C# implementation. Thanks for the link! :)

Comment: No worries. referencesource.microsoft.com is for the Framework sources, source.dot.net is for the Core sources